# Is there an English variant of "Zeitgeist" other than "spirit of the times"?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, german

Is there a cut-and-dry English word that means the same, or roughly the same, as the German word "Zeitgeist," other than its literal meaning of "spirit of the times"?

I've grown sour on its presence in conversational English due to heavy use as a clever buzzword and would like to know if there is a simpler alternative.

Comment: I don't think there's a precise substitute, which is why we encounter "Zeitgeist" so often, though I agree that not only conveys the idea but also is cloaked in pretension. Perhaps "social climate" is a workable substitute?

Comment: No other word means "zeitgeist". Only *zeitgeist* means "zeitgeist". (This is true of *all* words, by the way, and in all languages.) Everything else will mean something different. That is why it was borrowed in the first place: we did not have an equivalent of our own.

Comment: You might slip in *élan du jour* ocassionally, but it is neither english, nor a single word.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Aye, this was as I feared. I'm all for borrowed words, but this one seems borrowed a bit too over-zealously for my taste.

Comment: Have a look at Trends.

Comment: @DanBron "Cloaked in pretension" is precisely how I see most of its use. I do like "social climate" as an alternative.

Comment: @bright I'm not sure I agree. Frankly, I think your fear is rather irrational and a prime example of the red-car effect. Ngrams shows that the relative popularity of the word has barely tripled since 1970. (Even the relative popularity of such a mundane word as *despite* has increased tenfold in the last century.) If you specifically set out to look for red cars on the street, you will start seeing nothing but red cars absolutely everywhere. Most to the point: why let others coerce you into not using a word? If I keep repeating "beer" cloaked in pretension, will you stop using that one, too?

Comment: @RegDwigнt So you're claiming that synonyms don't exist?

Comment: @Superbest This has been covered before. 'True' (exactly overlapping and thus always interchangeable) synonyms are exceedingly rare (I'm still trying to separate 'abstruse' and 'recondite'), if they exist at all. The term is normally and sensibly used to mean 'words identical, or near-identical, in meaning and distribution over some subset of their usages'. Even a single word is infinitely polysemous.

Comment: I'm sticking with zeitgeist.  If it's used for long enough, it'll lose any notion of pretension, won't it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [thesaurus answer](http://thesaurus.com/browse/zeitgeist) gives some terms, but what's more interesting to me is the antonym *old-fashioned*. Based on that, I'd go with antonyms of *old-fashioned* which bring up such terms as **contemporary**, **fresh**, and **in vogue**. All of those terms, and especially the synonyms to [in vogue](http://thesaurus.com/browse/in%20vogue) work well.

In somewhat of a self-referential point of view, the use of the *zeitgeist* is pretty much *in vogue* today as *the latest thing* to discuss and, to turn a phrase, "word drop". At least, that's what my new friends who are all into Zeitgeist like to say.

Comment: I love the clever wordplay in your answer, @user2370114, as well as the thought on looking at the antonym for ideas.

Comment: Hi, I think lately the word "meta" is starting to shift toward something similar to zeitgeist. Seems to refer to something between zeitgeist and consensus and common sense

Answer (score 1):

Among the suggested  synonyms I think two of them may come close to the notion of 'spirit of time':

[atmosphere](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Atmosphere):

> - A dominant intellectual or emotional environment or attitude: the atmosphere  of the 50s.

[feeling:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/feeling)

> - an impression or mood; atmosphere: the feeling of a foreign city.