# "Zeitgeist" but for groups smaller than society as a whole?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests

Is there a word/phrase capturing the meaning of "zeitgeist" but not focused on society as a whole? Another German loan would be fine.

Some of the examples at [Word like "zeitgeist" for beliefs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319929/word-like-zeitgeist-for-beliefs) or [Is there an English variant of "Zeitgeist" other than "spirit of the times"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188680/is-there-an-english-variant-of-zeitgeist-other-than-spirit-of-the-times) are pretty good but don't connote everything I'm interested in (e.g., capturing both values and beliefs, suggesting temporality/changeability, being a noun and encompassing the entirety of thinking). In particular, "consensus" sounds too authoritative/permanent.

An example sentence: The XXX of archaeology favored "pots not people" over mass migration.

The best thing I can think of is just saying "zeitgeist of the academy" or "foo is in vogue in academia."

Comment: If it is mainly about a theory or (sophisticated) belief, *paradigm* might fit. But it depends on context. Another suggestion, if it is just a (well reasoned) opinion, is *communis opinio*; this works especially well for a widely shared view among a certain group of professionals or scientists.

Answer (score 2):

Another word would be ***vogue***:

> [**vogue**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vogue) The prevailing fashion or style at a particular time. General acceptance or favour; popularity.

Answer (score 1):

### [Fashion](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fashion)

If *consensus* is too permanent / authoritive then the more inherantly transient word *fashion* may be appropriate.

For example:

> The fashionable view of the archaeology community favored "pots not people" over mass migration.

This ODO example brings up *[sensibility](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sensibility)* as an interesting alternative:

> The fashions and sensibilities of popular culture contributed to the idea more than anything, even more than the nightly news.